# jquery/ajax general question about limits and cache management

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to renew my company intranet using jquery, ajax and php. General aspect of the site is a drop down menu at the top loaded into a div and a content div where i load pages clicked on drop-down menu. The problem come out when inside content i load a page which inside have a tab menu, what i do when a tab is clicked is to load a html structure page with form and fill it by POST call.

The question is it correct load data when requested instead of pre-load it and show them when called as seen in a lot of example in the web? Working in my way I get a lot of data cached so when i click for confirm some data I send request several data instead of one..
what is the best way to work with this languages?

I find my goal solution suggested by Nathan I *pre-load* all data in one time for all forms, here is the code:

```
$("#div_0").show();
        $("#scheda_eti > div").css({"background-color": "white", "color": "black","cursor":"hand"}); //tabs div
        $("#"+schemi[0]).css({"background-color": "red", "color": "white","cursor":"default"});
        for (var x=0; x<schemi.length; x++)
        {
            $("#div_"+x).load("./schemi/sch_"+schemi[x]+".php", {azione: "vedi"});
        }
        $.post("./php/global.php",
            {azione:"vedi", contratto: $("#suggest_hidden").val() },
            function(xml)
            {
                if ($("status", xml).text()=="1")
                {
                    $(xml).find("form").each(function()
                    {
                        var id_form=$(this).attr("id");
                        scorriDati(xml, "form_"+id_form);
                    });
                }
                else
                {
                    $("#scheda_ris").html("<img src='./img/validno.png' alt='errore'> <span style='color:red'><p>Attenzione!<br>codice non trovato!</p></span>");
                }
                $(xml).find("errore").each(function()
                {
                    $("#scheda_ris").append("<img src='./img/validno.png' alt='errore'> <span style='color:red'>"+$(this).text()+"<br></span>\n");
                });
            },'xml'
        );
```

To see some code you ca watch to my previous posts linked here:
[question1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4808294/jquery-ajax-problem-with-tab-menu)
[question2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4831722/jquery-ajax-post-not-append-data-to-form)

thanks in advance

ciao
h

Comment: I don't quite understand your question/problem. The point of AJAX is to load on request. Pre-loading AJAX seems to defeat the purpose of AJAX.

Comment: I think that too but for example all code that i find on the web to create a tab menu loads data of all tabs in an hidden div for ever tab and content is showed when clicked, what I do is load it dynamically when clicked i now may be not clear english is not my first language..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the answer to "is it correct load data when requested instead of pre-load it and show them when called?" is "which will the user prefer when switching to a different tab?"

1. no delay (all content loaded during initial page load)
2. short delay (ajax lookup of the new tab's content)
3. a full page load (a full round trip, no ajax needed)

In many cases you can get good results with the first or the third approach.  Don't overuse Ajax.

Here's [a blog rant about overuse/correct use of Ajax](http://www.mawhorter.net/web-development/the-overuse-of-ajax-and-how-to-be-a-good-ajax-developer)... I haven't honestly read it and don't necessarily endorse the whole thing, but it might help.

Comment: I've used your first suggestion! Now I correct my post with my code

Comment: @haltman and @Nathan: I would suggest a hybrid of 1 and 2 personally.  Preloading everything under the sun is bad since you're just increasing the generation time for a bunch of stuff that's never going to be used.  Instead, preload the commonly used data, and side-load (ajax lookup) less-needed content when it's needed.  That way you keep a good mix of load time with responsiveness...

Answer (score 2):

I think [jQuery UI Tabs](http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/#ajax) is what you're looking for. You need to include [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com) in your code, certainly **after** jQuery.

Order:

```
<link rel='stylesheet' href='http://jquery-ui.googlecode.com/svn/tags/latest/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css' />
<script src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js'></script>
<script src='http://jquery-ui.googlecode.com/svn/tags/latest/ui/minified/jquery-ui.min.js'></script>
```

If you don't like the UI lightness theme, you can choose any from the [Theme Gallery](http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/#themeGallery). For example, if you want the *UI darkness* theme, just replace `ui-lightness` with the theme's name in lowercase, and with hyphens instead of spaces.